# How to move the text from one div to another with every time the function run?

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to move the value from one div to another, when everytime the function has ran.

Here's an example: When `myfunction()` runs first time, it adds new text to `#current`, then the next time the `myfunction()` runs, it copies value from `#current` and gives to `#5`. After passing to `#5`, `#current` gets new value and the other divs keeps passing on till `#out`.

I hope this make sense and sorry for bad grammer.

```
<div id="last_container">
    <div id="out" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
    <div id="5"></div>
    <div id="current" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>

// first-run    
myFucntion() {
$("#last_container").appendTo('#current').append("1");  //1
}
// second-run
myFucntion() {
$("#last5").html($("#current").html());  //<div id="last5">1</div>
}
// third-run
myFucntion() {
$("#last4").html($("#last5").html());  //<div id="last4">1</div>
}
```

Here's JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/a26s5oxg/

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you expecting these functions to run?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, everytime a call has been made. Basically upon a button click this function will run.

Comment: A button click inside a form with an input? How would you know which number to pass?

Comment: Thanks @IslamElshobokshy, the number is randomly generated.

Comment: Can you please update your question and your code to add all of these important information? ^^'

Comment: I haven't gotten that far yet. I created an example on JSFiddle hoping this would work. but it didn't :(

Comment: Can you help with an example please? i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can place a class on the element to target. If that class is not available in the DOM you know that this is the first click and you instead need to set the `text()` in `#current`. If the class does exist, you need to go to the previous element and set the `text()` there instead. Note that in the example below the first click appears to do nothing as it's working on the `#current` element, which is hidden.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $target = $('div.active');
  
  if (!$target.length) {
    $('#current').text('1').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $target.removeClass('active').prev('div').addClass('active').text($target.text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="last_container">
    <div id="out" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
    <div id="5"></div>
    <div id="current" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't do exactly what he needs as if you replace `text('1')` with `text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1))` it'll keep replacing the same number.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy unless I'm missing something in the comments, that's what the question is asking for; the `1` gets assigned then copied to `#5`, `#4` and so on

Comment: Thank you very much @RoryMcCrossan and @Islam Elshobokshy. It is almost working.. The only problem is that, everytime `#current` passes the number to `#5` the `#current` get's a new value which it passes along. it's like a cycle > `#current` get new values and it passes along. Sorry for bad english and thank you once again :) I have marked the answer, but could you please give a suggestion on what to do please? thanks :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you please assist on the above query? I'd really appreciate it please.

Comment: The thing is everytime I click, `#current` isn't getting new value which needs to be passed to pre divs. I tried with `text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1))`. I am trying for `current` to get new values that passes to the prev divs please.